# sql sorting a column with numbers and words

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm having issues sorting a column of numbers and words a specific Ascending order of type `nvarchar`.

when I run this query

```
select GradedDescriptions from cards order by GradedDescriptions asc
```

I get

```
10
5
8
8.5
Authentic
Authentic
Black 10
```

But my desired result is

```
Authentic
5
8
8.5
10
Black 10
```

Is there a way to put Authentic before the numbers and Black 10 at the end?

Comment: And if Black 8 ... would that be between 8 and 8.5 ?

Comment: There is no black 8, only a black 10. The order is  Authentic, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5... 10, black 10

Comment: Are there really 2 instances of `Authentic` in your data?  Are DISTINCT values then also part of the desired result?

Comment: No there could N amounts. But I'd like Authentic to be before the numbers and black 10 to be after the numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps something like this

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([GradedDescriptions] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('10')
,('5')
,('8')
,('8.5')
,('Authentic')
,('Black 10')
 
Select * from @YourTable 
Order by try_convert(money,right([GradedDescriptions],3))
        ,[GradedDescriptions]
```

**Results**

```
GradedDescriptions
Authentic
5
8
8.5
10
Black 10
```

Comment: `money` really? https://sqlblog.org/2021/03/09/my-two-least-favorite-data-types What's wrong with `decimal`

Comment: @Charlieface Yes money,   It tends to be a little more forgiving in conversions and fewer keystrokes than decimal(#,#) .